Question about notation in graph-theoretic context
the following is the first page of Chapter 6 in the book Probabilistic Combinatorics by Thomas Rothvoss. Can someone please help me understand what $n$ means when they say that $G$ and $H$ differ in $\epsilon n^2$ edges? Also, at the end, they say talk about $O_{\epsilon}(1)$-many samples – what does this mean?


Just a guess based on my previous experiences with notation – is $n = |V|$?

As @SaksamSethi writes, it is a very common convention in graph theory to use $n$ for the number of a graph’s vertices and $m$ for the number of its edges. So absent an explicit definition in the text, or a list of symbols, or the like, that would be the near-universal interpretation. And it makes sense in the context because a graph on a set of $n$ vertices has ${n \choose 2} = \Theta(n^2)$ pairs of vertices (and thus potential edges).
